# Change object keys and value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this array of objects from an api:

```js
"use strict";

var data = [{
  "OPEN COVER (YES or NO)": "YES"
}, {
  "OPEN COVER (YES or NO)": "NO"
}, {
  "OPEN COVER (YES or NO)": "YES"
}];
var result = [];

data.map(function (item) {
  var fixed = {};
  var keys = Object.keys(item);
  keys.map(function (key) {
    if (key === 'OPEN COVER (YES or NO)') return fixed['open_cover'] = item[key];
  });
  result.push(fixed);
});
console.log(result);
```

How do i change the value from "YES" to true and "NO" to true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily convert a 'YES' to `true` and 'NO' to `false` using a ternary. Also, you can use a `forEach` instead of a `map`:

```js
"use strict";

var data = [{
  "OPEN COVER (YES or NO)": "YES"
}, {
  "OPEN COVER (YES or NO)": "NO"
}, {
  "OPEN COVER (YES or NO)": "YES"
}];
var result = data.reduce(function(items, item) {
  var fixed = {};
  var keys = Object.keys(item);
  keys.forEach(function(key) {
    if (key === 'OPEN COVER (YES or NO)') {
      return fixed['open_cover'] = item[key] === 'YES';
    }
  });
  items.push(fixed);
  return items;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Better is `item[key] === 'YES'` without the ternary, since this is already a boolean expression yielding a `false` or `true`.

Comment: @trincot Yes! Updated.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda if you are not returning anything in the map, you better use forEach. map() is used to iterate and create a new array based on a previous one. I have made an answer, based on your original one, using map.

Comment: @ChristianBenseler Updated to use reduce.

Comment: I think that using reduce to do this adds a lot of complexity, although it works. In the scenario described, where there is an array and it must returns a new one, use map() is more suited, because creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array. The reduce method is usually used to reduce an array to a single value.

Answer (score 2):

If you could use ES6 features, use map to iterates and returns a new array, creating a new object with spread operator for each array item

```
"use strict";

var data = [{
  "OPEN COVER (YES or NO)": "YES"
}, {
  "OPEN COVER (YES or NO)": "NO"
}, {
  "OPEN COVER (YES or NO)": "YES"
}];

const key = 'OPEN COVER (YES or NO)';

const result = data.map( item => {

  return {
    ...item,
    ...{
        [key]: item[key] === 'YES'
    }
  }
});
console.log(result);
```

Working fiddle, based on Chase DeAnda's original answer https://jsfiddle.net/xctohpw5/

Answer (score 0):

Or something like this, assuming that you will always have fixed key name `"OPEN COVER (YES or NO)"`:

```
"use strict";

var data = [{
  "OPEN COVER (YES or NO)": "YES"
}, {
  "OPEN COVER (YES or NO)": "NO"
}, {
  "OPEN COVER (YES or NO)": "YES"
}];
var result = data.map(function (item) {
 var tempObj = {};
 var key = Object.keys(item)[0];
 var value = item[key] === 'YES';

 tempObj[key] = value;

 return tempObj;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this would be to set the value to a simple statement.

`fixed['open_cover'] = item[key] === "YES"`

This will check if `item[key]` is equal to `"YES"` and set your output to `true` or `false`.